# Как инкрементировать в переменную все переходы в проекте.

Tags: ios, swift

Задача состоит в том чтобы поставить попап баннер, он будет появляться через N-ое количество переходов по Экранам, N-ое количество приходит с сервера. 
Я сделал синглтон в ней есть переменная и метод  который инкрементирует эту переменную, так вот я не хочу на каждом экране вызывать метод инкремента, как лучше будет это реализовать чтобы в одном месте прописать и он сам будет подсчитывать каждый переход. Спасибо.

```
class IncrementListView {
static let sharedInstance = IncrementListView()

/// popup
static var numberViewPopup = 0
static func incrementViewPopup() {
    numberViewPopup  += 1
    print("number view numberViewPopup = \(numberViewPopup)")
}

static func killNumberPopupView() {
    numberViewPopup = 0
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что у вас метод инкремента вызывается, например, из метода viewDidAppear, то можно создать базовый класс для всех UIViewController, участвующих в переходах:

```
import UIKit

class IncrementableViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        IncrementListView.incrementViewPopup()
    }

}
```

А затем все UIViewController'ы наследовать от этого класса:

```
import UIKit

class SomeViewController: IncrementableViewController {

    // ...

}
```

И тогда всякий раз, когда у какого-либо UIViewConroller'a сработает viewDidAppear, будет вызываться и метод инкремента вашего синглтона.

Comment: сделал, ставлю брекпоинт во viewDidAppear, приходится вызывать в  SomeViewController в методе viewDidLoad {super.viewDidAppear(true)}

Comment: Вариант подошел, я тут же и сделал проверку на попа и отображение попапа, Вот только утечка происходит, память начала жрать.